# PDB files and source not in sync

Tags: .net, debugging, pdb-files, ndepend

I am trying to analyse some assemblies with NDepend but it complains that the pdb files and source files are not in sync with each other. However, the development and compilation of the assemblies has occured on the same server as where I am running NDepend from.

How can I fix this? I've seen a lot of people have this problem, from googling, but no real solutions. Also, I will be running NDepend on another server (automated build server) from the dev server, so in the future, I am likely to have the same problem again. Looking at NDepend's documentation, the path to where the source is stored must always be the same (but I never broke this rule).

Would a recompilation of the assembly fix this? How serious is this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I have never used NDepend but a recompilation would be the first think I would try. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NDepend emits a 'PDB files and source not in sync' simply when it detects that a source file referenced by a [PDB file](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Inputs.aspx) has a more recent LastWriteTime than the PDB file. So if your build process somehow updates the LastWriteTime of your source file after compilation and before NDepend analysis this can be a false alarm, although changing the LastWriteTime of your source file after compilation sounds awkward.

A better heuristic could be to harness source files checksums contained in PDB file. By using this checksum NDepend could see if the source file content has been changed. This is how VS is working btw at debugging time. We (the NDepend Team) haven't implement this heuristic because it could be costly and the simple heuristic based on LastWriteTime is enough for most of real-world cases.

Patrick - NDepend Team

Comment: Any idea where to find the checksums for the source files in a pdb? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120215/how-does-visual-studio-know-if-the-source-file-matches-the-original-version-c-s

Comment: Not sure if Mono.Cecil.PDB or MS CCI PDB have this feature now? Just check it: http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/discussions/topics/4673/pdb-reader

Comment: I found the MD5 checksums. I was able to modify the MS CCI PDB code to get to them. I don't understand why everything in that code base is marked as internal. I'm probably going to write my own reader.